# Parse below URL in bash

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, url

I have a URL like "**http://host:port/cgi-bin/hw.sh/some/path/to/data/**".
For the above URL i only need to get the value "**/some/path/to/data/**".
How can I fetch the required value from the above URL in a shell script.

Comment: Is the `hw.sh` part fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `awk` `-F` option to specify `"hw.sh"` as the field input separator and print the second field:

`$ echo "http://host:port/cgi-bin/hw.sh/some/path/to/data/" | awk -F"hw.sh" '{print $2}'`

`/some/path/to/data/`

Or a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

`awk -F"hw.sh" '{print $2}' <<< "http://host:port/cgi-bin/hw.sh/some/path/to/data/"`

Comment: The OP said, "_How can I fetch the required value from the above URL in a shell script._" **not** from the Command Line.

Comment: True, script added.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is "everything after `hw.sh`", it's very easy:

```
#!/bin/sh
url='http://host:port/cgi-bin/hw.sh/some/path/to/data/'
path=${url#*hw.sh}
echo $path
```

Which will give you:

```
/some/path/to/data/
```

See the "Parameter expansion" section of the [bash man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Also, as I am new to shell scripting, could you/anyone suggest some guide or link to have a look at the way parsing is done in bash. This would be of great help. TIA.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "parsing", but I find that the `bash` man page is a good place to start, in particular because it has lots of details about how variable expansion works. The [bash faq](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) is also a good resource.